# How to delete all items from a Sharepoint List using Python REST?

Tags: python, rest, http, sharepoint, crud

I am trying to delete all the items from a Sharepoint List using Python. However, there is no official documentation of Sharepoint REST that supports Python. I have gone through many StackOverflow articles and have built up the python code to delete a single item. However, I am unable to understand how to delete all items at once. Also, iteration over all would be quite complex, since GET request returns a JSON with a lot of unnecessary metadata as well, hence parsing is a challenge. Hence, I am unable to go about deleting all the items at once. Currently I am using `requests.post(https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items(id), auth, headers)` and specifying the following headers: `X-RequestDigest: digestValue`, `X-HTTP-Method: DELETE`, and `IF-MATCH: *`. This is working perfectly well and I am able to delete an item by its `id` but unable to delete all items of the list.

Any help is appreciated, especially involving using python `requests` as I am using that to perform CRUD operations. Also, the same code gives `Bad Request` error if I use `https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items/getitembyid(id)` instead of `https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items(id)`. Besides, I am also unable to delete by using `requests.post(https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items?filter=Title eq 'title1'`. It gives Bad Request once again. In both cases, apart from the Bad Request error, when I try to log it, it gives the following exception: `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException` with the error content saying `The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP DELETE method`. Any insights into this are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to delete all list items at once. SharePoint Rest API has not exposed such an endpoint. We suggest you delete item one by one, put the delete request in a loop like below:

```html
function deleteItem(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        for(var item in items){
            var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyList')/getItemById(item.ID)"
            deleteItem(url);
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

More references:

- [Delete all items from SharePoint](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/how-to-delete-all-items-from-sharepoint-online-list-using-rest-api/)